# Printing specific value from list (text file in python)

Tags: python, arrays

I have a text file that reads the following and is called split.txt:

```
18, 1, 3, 4, 35
42, 6, 9, 12, 24
2, 22, 45, 91, 75
```

I want to print ONLY the last number in each line and I did that by doing this:

```
with open("split.txt", "rt") as split:
   for line in split:
        print (line.strip()[-2:])
```

How would I edit my code so that I am able to print ONLY the number that are greater than 50? So I'm not sure how to make an if statement to output my desired results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get each line as variable `line` in the loop, split it with a comma, and get the last item with indexing at [-1]. Assuming it will always be a number, cast it to int. The strip() won't be absolutely necessary as `int('  23  ')` will still be an integer `23`.

```
with open("split.txt", "rt") as split:
   for line in split:
       last_number = int(line.split(',')[-1].strip())
       if last_number > 50:
           print(last_number)
```